# Why are there two of the same file in my network tab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am currently trying to use require to import the module "js-big-decimal".  I am getting the errors:

```
js-big-decimal.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at js-big-decimal.js:10
```

```
require.js:1961 GET https://igneous-spider-328623.uk.r.appspot.com/js-big-decimal.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "js-big-decimal"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738)
```

I'm assuming this because I have a syntax error somewhere when trying to import my modules.  In my HTML I have:

```
<script src="/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/js-big-decimal"></script>
```

and in my javascript I have:

```
require(['require', 'js-big-decimal'], function (require) {
    var bigDecimal = require('./node_modules/js-big-decimal')
});
```

And in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js-big-decimal": "^1.3.4",
    "nodejs": "0.0.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
  }
```

When looking in my network tab, it shows that I have two different version of js-big-decimal.js and I am getting a 404 on one of them, as seen below:

[image: Network tab]

I've never really looked in the network tab so I'm not sure what I'm looking at.  But if anyone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong would be great.

Comment: You might be trying to import a nodejs module into a browser context?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: never mind. I just looked at the docs and I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Is it possible that you really do have 2 different versions? Maybe delete node_modules, reinstall and see if the problems still exists. If so, maybe another package is requiring the other version for some reason

Comment: Do you need the second require call in your javascript? According to the docs, the BigDecimal should be available on the Window object when used with the web script tags.

Comment: For web, when used with script tag, a variable on Window object is created. <script src="node_modules/js-big-decimal/dist/web/js-big-decimal.min.js"></script>

Comment: @DovRine I'm not sure what you mean.   Do you mean that I don't need the require(['require', 'js-big-decimal'] call? Because taking that out and leaving the var bigDecimal = require('js-big-decimal') gives me Uncaught Error: Module name "js-big-decimal" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded .  I'm just not exactly sure what the proper procedure is for importing modules like this.

Comment: These are the docs I was looking at and it seems to me like it's one or the other. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal

Comment: I now see what you mean and it resolved itself.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.